# How to solve this issue while updating?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, x121e

I have the following error message:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Duplicate question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process

Comment: that error is as a result of a lock on the package manager.. it appears you already have an installation taking place so wait for the other process to end or kill it and relaunch the PM

Comment: If you do not post *exactly* which command you are using no one will be able to help --- we are in short supply of crystal balls. Are you using `sudo`, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

Either something else is using the package manager (do you have any GUI's such as the software center open? You need to close those!), or you did not run an apt command as `sudo`. eg.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you did run the apt command as `sudo` and there are no other applications using the package manager, try rebooting or logging off & on again.

If you still get this error, you can manually remove the lock, but this is not advised:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```